# tidy_repair_string removes end line break (\n or \r)

Tags: php, htmltidy

```
$HTMLcodeOutput = tidy_repair_string($HTMLcode, array('show-body-only' => true, 'indent' => true));
```

will remove $HTMLcode' end of line.
Ex :

```
that's in the main box



##What does it do ?

it does everything



##Output:
```

Will output

```
that's in the main box ##What does it do ? it does everything
##Output: I will giv ea a grat output
```

This wouldn't be a problem if this string wasn't echoed into a < pre > tag thereafter. Thus, the \n or \r character IS important.
I had a look at the documentation, but couldn't find anything obvious.

Is there any way to keep these line return characters ?

(Adding  tags before using tidy string repair is a bad idea, as it will result in echoing the <pre> tags visible in the browser, as string (decoded), and not as tags.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you are trying to format html for human readability, and you don't want to use "pre" tags to force tidy to preserve whitespace because you will be running the output of tidy through htmlspecialchars before outputting it to the browser.

Why don't you just remove those "pre" tags after cleaning?  It would look like this:

```
$config = array('show-body-only' => true, 'indent' => true);
$HTMLcodeOutput = tidy_repair_string('<pre>'.$HTMLcode.'</pre>', $config);
$HTMLcodeOutput = substr($HTMLcodeOutput, 5, -6);
```